# How to convert a C function call in C++ compatible syntax?

Tags: c++, c

I've a question about *handler function, I can't understand what is this and in code there is not a declaration of this function. 
I've this code in C `modesReadFromClient(client *c, char *sep, int (*handler)(client *));`

Now I want to use this in `C++`. In header file I've this code  -

```
void modesReadFromClient(client *c, char *sep, int (*handler)(client *));
```

And in source file this code -

```
void MainWindow::modesReadFromClient(struct client *c, char *sep,
                     int(*handler)(struct client *))
```

But I've an error -

> invalid use of non-static member function `modesReadFromClient(c,"\n",HexMessage);`

I think that something is wrong with the `int* handler`. How do I translate this code to C++?

Comment: Can you please post `HexMessage`?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the callback handler, it sounds like you're trying to call `modesReadFromClient` without an instance of `MainWindow`. You need something like `MainWindow m; m.modesReadFromClient(...);`

Comment: hexmessage is a function

Comment: _"I have this code in C"_ That's unlikely as it's a member of a class `MainWindow` and C does not have classes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is the code https://github.com/antirez/dump1090/blob/master/dump1090.c line 2103, i try to make a gui with QT/C++

Comment: I am not reading 2,103 lines. Produce a meaningful and relevant [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should already have one from the first few hours of debugging this issue.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit of course you dont have to read all the lines, but in this line is only this function.

Comment: @xmaze: Please read my comment again, and the page I linked you to. Testcases are a requirement here, not a request.

Comment: We need to see both the declaration of `HexMessage` and the context where `modesReadFromClient` is called. If `HexMessage` is a member function of a class, this won't work. C++ methods can't be cast as regular function pointers, but you might be able to rework this to work with pointers to members.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to make a debug or a minimal testcase i think needs and a functional code, if i cannot build the code how can i make this test? if u have a better idea i am glad to hear u.

Comment: @xmaze: The testcase demonstrates the problem (be it a runtime or a compile-time error). That's its entire purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a function pointer, you can then call `handler()` from within the `modesReadFromClient();` function.

The declaration

```
int (*handler)(struct client *)
```

makes `handler` a function pointer, you can then call `handler` like this

```
struct client *someClient;
int            handlerResult;
/* initialize someClient */
handlerResult = handler(someClient);
```

If you have a handler function like this one

```
int handlerFunction(struct client *c)
{
    /* do somthing with 'c' */
}
```

then you can call

```
modesReadFromClient(c, "\n", handlerFunction);
```

Comment: @xmaze i am not c++ expert, but you need both solutions apparently.

Comment: ok, thank u, but if u want a better view look the source code at https://github.com/antirez/dump1090/blob/master/dump1090.c Line 2103 Line 2295

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a non-static function in C++, declare an instance of the class and call the function on that instance.

```
MainWindow mainWindow;
mainWindow.modesReadFromClient(...);
```